# QAudioFormat with Wave File

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt5, audioformat

Is it possible to use the `QAudioFormat` class on a wave file? I would like to use the class to get information about the wave file, like sample rate and bit rate.

Looking into the documentation didn't help that much, I could find a function to pass the file into the `QAudioFormat` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is - looking at the documentation.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#supportedCodecs

> All platform and plugin implementations should provide support for:
>
> "audio/pcm" - Linear PCM

Wikipedia on WAV files says: "The usual bitstream encoding [for WAV files] is the linear pulse-code modulation (LPCM) format."